# Select2 squishing dropdowns lists in bootstrap tabs

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, jquery-select2

I am using bootstrap tabs and am making use of `select2` plugin (searchable dropdown list)

I have multiple tabs but for some reason, whenever I am using the `select2` in the tabs any other than the active tab on load, the drop-down lists are just bunching up without obeying the `col-md-3` class I am giving them. Instead they squish up. The drop-down list in the 1st active class that shows on page load obeys the class correctly.

I recreated a sample in jsfiddle with test data which can be accessed **[HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/7em4z1h8/2/)**. 
Section B drop-down list does not obey the `col-md-3`class, although class A does.

Any help? Honestly I do NOT wish to use `style="width:100%"` or fiddle around with any styles due to mobile responsiveness.
Thanks again.

EDIT: I have tested this in Opera Browser, Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome. The worst hit is Opera. Google Chrome best responded where this problem did not always reproduce

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.fn.select2.defaults.set("theme", "classic");
  $("#carsA").select2();
  $('#second').on('click',function(){
     setTimeout(function(){$("#carsB").select2();},200);
  })
})
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hy5man/7em4z1h8/6/).

You have to initialize Select2 when you trigger on the tab. So it gets fit into the assigned class `col-md-3` width. Usage of time interval is to prevent it to initialize, before the HTML responsive construction. Increase time interval if necessary. I think this is the way to solve without CSS styles.